# Rule CSS partially applied

Tags: html, css, extjs3

I've this code

```
<div id="editGridReglas" class=" x-row-editor x-small-editor" style="position: absolute; z-index: 11000; width: 1033px; left: 0px; top: 126px; visibility: visible; ">
    <div class="x-row-editor-header x-unselectable" id="ext-gen296" style="-webkit-user-select: none; ">
    <span class="x-row-editor-header-text">
    </span></div>
    <div class="x-row-editor-bwrap" id="ext-gen297">
        <div class="x-box-inner" id="ext-gen308" style="width: 1033px; height: 22px; ">
            <div id="ext-comp-1083" name="ext-comp-1083" class=" x-form-display-field x-box-item" style="width: 22px; left: 1px; top: 0px; ">
            </div>
            <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" id="ideprodcnt" name="ideprodcnt" 
                class="x-form-text x-form-field x-box-item" style="width: 251px; left: 24px; top: 0px; " title="">
            <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" id="ideplan" name="ideplan" 
                class="x-form-text x-form-field x-box-item" style="width: 251px; left: 276px; top: 0px; " title="">
            <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" id="iderev" name="iderev" 
                class="x-form-text x-form-field x-box-item" style="width: 251px; left: 528px; top: 0px; " title="">
            <div class="x-form-check-wrap x-box-item" id="ext-gen319" style="width: 249px; left: 781px; top: 0px; ">
                <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" id="estado" name="estado" class=" x-form-checkbox x-form-field" checked="">
                <label for="estado" class="x-form-cb-label" id="ext-gen320">&nbsp;</label>
            </div>
            <div id="ext-comp-1078" name="ext-comp-1078" class="x-form-display-field" style="width: 22px; left: 1px; top: 0px; ">
            </div>
            <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" id="ideprodcnt" name="ideprodcnt" 
                class="x-form-text x-form-field" style="width: 251px; left: 25px; top: 0px; " title="">
            <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" id="ideplan" name="ideplan" 
                class="x-form-text x-form-field" style="width: 251px; left: 278px; top: 0px; " title="">
            <input type="text" size="20" autocomplete="off" id="iderev" name="iderev" 
                class="x-form-text x-form-field" style="width: 251px; left: 531px; top: 0px; " title="">
            <div class="x-form-check-wrap" id="ext-gen309" style="width: 249px; left: 785px; top: 0px; ">
                <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" id="estado" name="estado" class=" x-form-checkbox x-form-field" checked="">
                <label for="estado" class="x-form-cb-label" id="ext-gen310">&nbsp;</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to hide all inputs haven't the word "x-box-item" in their class with exception of this component:

```
<input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" id="estado" name="estado" class=" x-form-checkbox x-form-field" checked="">
```

This component is inside a div label:

```
<div class="x-form-check-wrap x-box-item" id="ext-gen319" style="width: 249px; left: 781px; top: 0px; ">
                <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" id="estado" name="estado" class=" x-form-checkbox x-form-field" checked="">
                <label for="estado" class="x-form-cb-label" id="ext-gen320">&nbsp;</label>
            </div>
```

I'm using this rule css:

```
#editGridReglas input:not(.x-box-item){
    visibility: hidden;
}

#editGridReglas div .x-box-item input[type=checkbox]{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Both rules work fine but anyway I want to know if I'm using correctly the CSS rules

[EDIT]

On IE 8

```
#editGridReglas input.x-form-text.x-form-field {
    visibility: hidden;
}

#editGridReglas input.x-box-item {
    visibility: visible !important;
}

#editGridReglas div.x-form-check-wrap.x-box-item input{
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use `#estado {visibility:visible;}`  since it has an ID.    If it has trouble showing up, you could put `!important` in the secondary rule:

`#estado {visibility:visible !important;}`

or

`#editGridReglas div input[type=checkbox]:not(.x-box-item) {visibility:visible !important;}`

if the ID is back-ended, and the CSS won't know IDs.

edit 2:  adding a third way, from my comment below.

`div.x-box-item input[type=checkbox] {visibility:visible !important}`

This one finds the DIV with x-box-item as a class, input-checkboxes inside it, and makes them visible.   According to your HTML above, should work.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the identifiers are referential because in the application are auto generated. I'm work with ExtJS and I'm implementing RowEditor plugin (http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/grid/row-editor.html)

Comment: I've just updated my response above, take a look and see if it works.   The final one.   It's almost the same as your top one, but making sure it's not an .x-box-item and inside a div and is a checkbox

Comment: or `div.x-box-item input[type=checkbox] {visibility:visible !important}` -- to focus on the DIV and input-checkboxes inside it.   That would work, too.    Not sure if `type=checkbox` needs to be `type='checkbox'` (single quotes) or not.

Comment: In the end, just pick the one that's most readable, the easiest to understand -- so when you revisit it 6 months from now, you don't have the "what the #^@#!@# was I doing here?!"

Comment: This don't work in IE 7/8 :(

Comment: I believe that ie7/8 do not support the .has or .not conditions.   Check the Internet to see if there are polyfill shims for it.